# Why is this JavaScript if statement always returning true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am trying to execute a block of code when a div is clicked for the first time, and then a different block when it is clicked the second time. My alert shows that the variable is being changed within the first block, but the first code block always executes.

If I change the variable manually, I can get the second block to execute.

```
var clickCount = 0;

        // code for first click 
        if ( clickCount === 0 ){
            $( '.link' ).click(function(){
                alert( 'first click. clickCount = ' + clickCount );
                clickCount = 1;                 
            });
        }

        // code for second click 
        if ( clickCount === 1 ){
            $( '.link' ).click(function(){
               alert( 'first click. clickCount = ' + clickCount ); // never executes
                // stuff
            });
        }
```

Comment: Hint: it's not _always_ true. It's tested _once_.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak Is it not tested on the second click?

Comment: The second if statement will execute right after the first one, so clickCount will still be 0.

Comment: perhaps try to change === into == ...

Comment: is that the code the runs on every div click?

Comment: when if conditions are evaluated the clickcount is 0 so only the first handler is registered and the second one is not.

Comment: add ````else```` before second if. Whats happening is, initially code runs for clickcount==0 and then you increment it to 1 and as soon as code goes out, i encounter clickcount == 1 (which you have just done), so thats code runs too.

Comment: What is the context of this code? Why binding two handlers? You should check for clickCount inside click handler

Comment: @thescientist it should run on just divs with the class "link".

Comment: @A. Wolff I'm trying to rework :hover behavior for touch devices. I think you're on to something - I'll try to check clickCount in the handler.

Comment: @Sauce that's what I thought.  by now though you should be able to see from the answers that the issue is the conditional being outside of the setting of the click handler.  you need to do the clickCount toggling within the event handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code says:

```
If the variable is 0
attach a click handler to the link which fires every time the link is clicked
```

That click handler stays there, even after the variable has changed. The condition is only evaluated once and the click handler is only attached once, but that's all that's necessary to keep triggering the attached click handler every time the link is clicked henceforth.

The second block is never executed, unless you run this whole block of code again that attaches the click handlers.

You probably just want to attach one click handler once, and inside that handler you check the value of `clickCount` and do something different based on its value.

```
var clickCount = 0;

$('.link').click(function () {
    alert('clickCount = ' + clickCount);

    if (clickCount === 0) {
        clickCount = 1;                 
    } else {
        // stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you:

```
var clickCount = 0;

$('.link').click(function() {
    if (clickCount === 0) {
        alert('first click. clickCount = ' + clickCount);
        clickCount = 1;
    }
    else {
        alert('second and further clicks. clickCount = ' + clickCount);
    }
});
```

You don't need to bind event twice. Once is enough. Just check inside of a click handler number of clicks and execute corresponding code.